# How can I verify regular WAF expression syntax and test it for AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-waf

I have configured a AWS API gateway (GET and POST ) method for pet store project(POC) and have to configure few WAF rules to my below sample JSON structure.

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "dog",
    "price": 249.99
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "type": "cat",
    "price": 124.99
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "type": "fish",
    "price": 0.99
}
]
```

Now I'm trying to configure a custom AWS WAF rules with the help of Rule builder.

WAF rule 1 : Object Entry count(10)

If JSON body Object Entry count is more than 10+ then WAF custom rule( regular expression ) should block that API request.

I created a regular expression like below :

```
"[^"]":\s("[^"]"|\d|true|false|null)(,\s*"[^"]":\s("[^"]"|\d|true|false|null)){0,9}
```

WAF rule 2: Array Entry Count(20)
If JSON body Array Entry count is more than 20+ then WAF custom rule should block that API request.

```
\[([^\[\]]("[^"]")[^\[\]](,\s[^\[\]]("[^"]")[^\[\]]*){0,119})?\]
```

WAF rule3 : Container Depth(6)
JSON body Container Depth is not more than 6. If more, then WAF custom rule should block that API request.

```
[^\{\}]\{[^\{\}]\{[^\{\}]\{[^\{\}]\{[^\{\}]\{[^\{\}]\}
```

Now my question is that How can I verify regular expression syntax and test it for above requirements? I feel syntax is wrong, but I'm not sure about this.
Can someone please help me to resolve this case?